# LIKE clause is not working in $wpdb->prepare() in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am creating simple searching script with LIKE clause. 
Below is the simple query with LIKE clause using php.

```
$rows = mysql_query("select * from description where tags like '%{$keyword}%'");
```

This above query work successfully. But LIKE clause not working with `$wpdb->prepare()`. Below is the code for that

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("select * from description where tags like '%{%s}%'",$keyword));
```

What I am missing in this?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve this issue? I have the same

Answer (score 0):

I usually use sprintf, and do something similar to this.

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr = sprintf(
"SELECT * FROM description WHERE tags LIKE '%%%$s%%'"
mysql_real_escape_string($s)
)
$rows = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
echo "</pre>"; print_r($rows); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks @galfaro...but its not working. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the % character,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$param = "%{$keyword}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM description WHERE tags LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  foreach ($row as $r) {
    print "$r ";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks @payer...but it is displaying 2 errors as follows `Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\employer\wp-content\themes\i-craft\resumes_pages\search.php on line 40 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\employer\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1210`

Comment: And 2nd error is `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\employer\wp-content\themes\i-craft\resumes_pages\search.php on line 42`

Comment: try this one: $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT column_1 from `{$wpdb->base_prefix}my_table` WHERE column_2 LIKE %s;", '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($number_to_put_in_like) . '%');